# A required file could not be downloaded while installing SQL Server 2019 Developer

Tags: sql-server

While Installing SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition, I am getting error - A required file could not be downloaded. This could mean the version of the installer is no longer supported. Please download again from download site.

[image]

I am not getting what is missing file and how to resolve this.

Comment: The hint is in the message, download the installer again and try with the new installer

Comment: I tried downloading multiple times from different network and different browser. It downloads same the file and I get same error.

Comment: check the logs, it must be creating some log file duration the installation process, what file it is complaining about and see if that file exists

Comment: You should give green tick to approve best answer for user Mike.

Comment: Stop using the web installer and download the ISO directly from [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/c/1/7c14e92e-bdcb-4f89-b7cf-93543e7112d1/SQLServer2019-x64-ENU-Dev.iso). See [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71925659/61305) for links to other threads.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Open PowerShell as administrator and run

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword
```

Source https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/sql-server-installer-unable-to-download-the-required-files/m-p/2120065/highlight/true#M890

Comment: This also fixes the same error message when installing SQL Express 2019.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. You have to press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and write '`regedit`'. In the opened window follow this path:

1. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319

   In this folder press the right button and click on '**New**' -> '**DWORD (32 - bit) Value**' with name '`SchUseStrongCrypto`' and value '**1**'.
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319

   In this folder press the right button and click on '**New**' -> '**DWORD (32 - bit) Value**' with name '`SchUseStrongCrypto`' and value '**1**'.
3. After that you can run and install *Sql Server 2019*.

Comment: There is a backslash missing between "Microsoft" and ".NetFramework".

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set a proxy for required file download. This solution worked for me.
I used a VPN software to download required file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem recently - it was accompanied by an error in the Event Viewer System log, with source `Schannel`:

`A fatal error occurred while creating an SSL client credential. The internal error state is 10013.`

This error indicates that the issue is related to the connection itself, rather than the specific installer file being downloaded.

I found a solution on the Microsoft TechCommunity site, linked at the bottom. Once I'd applied the cryptography change, the download worked immediately, no need for a different installer.

1. Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy.
2. In Local Security Settings, expand Local Policies, and then click Security Options.
3. Under Policy in the right pane, double-click System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption, hashing, and signing, and then click Enabled.
4. Run gpupdate /force

Source: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/sql-server-installer-unable-to-download-the-required-files/m-p/163982/highlight/true#M108

Answer (score 0):

Go to START and type "Windows Powershell". Click "Run as Administrator"

[image: Open as Powershell]

After clicking, the following blue screen cmd will be visible:

[image: cmd]

Type the following two commands:

Commands

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword
 
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type Dword
```

Source video: https://youtu.be/F5worx5wbOs

**Note:** Open Powershell as an admin, else it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Registry key edits didn't work for me.  I ended up just downloading and installing [SQL Express](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/c/1/7c14e92e-bdcb-4f89-b7cf-93543e7112d1/SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe).  I didn't want to install SQL Express edition, I wanted Developer Edition.  At least I've got something and now I can try to figure if Express will do the job for my development work.  If not I'll have to figure out how to upgrade express.

Answer (score 0):

**Instalation requires access to the internet** which was not accessible in my case, so i **opened firewall** for a moment to finish this instalation.

**in other cases it is usefull to read the logs:**

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\SSEI\LogFiles

**NOTE:**  150 is version so your path could be different