# Microsoft SQL Server Express: this version of the installer is no longer supported

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I'm trying to install Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Express but I keep running into the above error message.

I was originally running into a separate error message when trying to install that said

> A required file could not be downloaded

I followed the instructions on the following thread, which solved the original issue, but now I have a new error: [A required file could not be downloaded while installing SQL Server 2019 Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526369/a-required-file-could-not-be-downloaded-while-installing-sql-server-2019-develop)

There doesn't seem to be much info about this online, only thread I've found is brand new and I'll be monitoring it for a solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/816770/sql-express-2019-the-version-of-the-installer-is-n.html

I have already tried restarting my computer.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: The web installers are currently broken, and Microsoft is aware of the issue - some conflict between a recent Windows update and a secure file. There is a cumbersome workaround involving PowerShell but much simpler to just direct download [this ISO](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/c/1/7c14e92e-bdcb-4f89-b7cf-93543e7112d1/SQLServer2019-x64-ENU-Dev.iso) and bypass the web stuff altogether - it's labeled Developer Edition but you should be able to choose Express as the edition.

Comment: Some other threads that may or may not be helpful: [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/801165/can39t-install-sql-server-2019.html) [two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/464840/unable-to-install-sql-server-2019-developer-versio.html)

Comment: If you're trying the registry hacks from Aaron's `one` and `two` links please note that the Registry paths are incorrect, i.e.: `...\Microsoft.NetFramework\...` is missing a backslash and should be `...\Microsoft\.NetFramework\...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply AlwaysLearning! By entering the incorrect commands, is there something I should now reverse or did nothing happen when i entered the commands? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I'm trying the ISO now and hopefully it works. Do you have a source that states the web browsers are currently broken? I want to post it as an answer and close this thread.

Comment: Maybe this thread will help but I'm not sure there's been an official response from Microsoft yet: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/sql-server-installer-unable-to-download-the-required-files/m-p/163982/highlight/true#M108

Comment: Using the incorrect paths won't break anything, it just creates registry paths and values that aren't consulted by .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again today with a new download and it worked! They must have fixed the issue. Hopefully everyone else can get it running today.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I executed the Powershell script as mentioned in the other thread (run powershell as an administrator), restarted my PC and used the re-downloaded installer (from the url in the error message). This time the installer went through. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that didn't work for me though.

Comment: It won't work (at least for the past 1 month, 1 endless loop)